# CSV stock import for Prestashop 1.6

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop

I would like to create a simple php script that I can run a stock overwrite to my products in Prestashop 1.6. It will need to reference the "product reference" which in my file is "SKU" and then update the "quantity" in Prestashop which is "Available Stock" in my spreadsheet.

At present I am updating this manually every day as I am given a csv file with live stock updates from my supplier. I have seen modules but none of them seem to work for us so hoping theres a simple maybe php script someone has created that would just overwrite the data in the db.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you done so far ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an script i use on PS 1.6 for update stock for "product" or "product_attribute" by UPC.

the CSV file in stock/ folder look like :

product ref;stock move;id shop
4443601522;0;1

you can change this scrit to use SKU instead of UPC

```
<?php
include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/config/config.inc.php');
include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/init.php');

$id_shop     = 1;
$id_lang     = 1;
$ligne       = 0; 
$dossier_csv = "/home/mywebsite/public_html/stock/"; 

echo '<H1>MAJ PS STOCK PAR UPC</h1>';

if (($fic = fopen($dossier_csv . "stock.csv", "a+")) == FALSE) {
    echo '<br>Erreur ouverture fichier stock !<br>';
} else {
    echo '<h2><u>Traitement des stocks :</u></h2>';
}


while ($tab = fgetcsv($fic, 1024, ';')) {
    $champs = count($tab);

    $ligne++;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $champs; $i++) {

        if ($i == 0)
            $reference = $tab[$i];

        if ($i == 1 && $reference != '' && $ligne != 1) {
            $quantity  = $tab[$i];
            $productId = getIdProductByUPC($reference);

            if ($productId != false) {

                $idProductAttribute = getIdByUPC($productId, $reference);
                $newStock           = $quantity;

                StockAvailable::setQuantity($productId, $idProductAttribute, $newStock, $id_shop);


                echo '<br>(' . $reference . ')  : OK qte : <b>' . $quantity . '</b><br>';
            } else {
                $productId = Product::getIdByUPC($reference);

                $product     = new Product($productId);
                $combination = $product->getAttributeCombinations($id_lang);

                if ($productId != false && count($combination) == 0) {
                    $newStock = $quantity;
                    StockAvailable::setQuantity($productId, 0, $newStock, $id_shop);
                    echo '<br>(' . $reference . ')  : OK qte : <b>' . $quantity . '</b><br>';
                } else {
                    echo '<br>(' . $reference . '-' . $productId . ')  : Erreur enregistrement stock <br>';
                }
            }  
        }

    }   
}

echo '<br><br><br><br>---MAJ TERMINEE---';

function getIdByUPC($id_product, $reference)
{
    if (empty($reference)) {
        return 0;
    }

    $query = new DbQuery();
    $query->select('pa.id_product_attribute');
    $query->from('product_attribute', 'pa');
    $query->where('pa.upc LIKE \'%' . pSQL($reference) . '%\'');
    $query->where('pa.id_product = ' . (int) $id_product);

    return Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->getValue($query);
}

function getIdProductByUPC($reference)
{
    if (empty($reference))
        return 0;
    $query = new DbQuery();
    $query->select('pa.id_product');
    $query->from('product_attribute', 'pa');
    $query->where('pa.upc = \'' . pSQL($reference) . '\'');
    return Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->getValue($query);
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks for this. Would it be possible to see the headers on your .csv file so I know what I need to update as I am very new to this. Thanks in advance

Comment: my columns names are : (  product ref;stock move;id shop  )  , i put the csv file here : https://www.justbeamit.com/8x2eg

Comment: the link work only the first time, so use this one  https://www.justbeamit.com/u7tbp

Comment: so , it works ? you can show your code if you need more help

Comment: Our code is the same as yours as we're unsure what parts we need to alter. Our columns in our csv file are sku;location;stock available. We need the script to check the sku from the file with the reference from the database and update the stock available which is column 3 in the database with the values from the csv.

Comment: location is id_shop ? in your CSV, if yes you need to invert last two cols

Comment: location isn't relevant to prestashop sorry. This is a field downloaded from the supplier which is standard but nothing to do with the stock allocation on our database.

Comment: for your tests only, please try with just 3 cols in csv (product reference,stock movement, id_shop), i use this script in production, it s working with UPC reference) you can also try to fill UPC field just to see. there is no error when you execute the script ?

Answer (score -1):

I think, line $productId = Product::getIdByUPC($reference) is wrong.
The correct: $productId = getIdProductByUPC($reference)